# ansible multiple handlers giving syntax error

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am writing a playbook to install docker and here it is:

```
- name: "Install docker on Xubuntu slave"
  hosts: "{{ variable_host | default('web') }}"
  become: True
  tasks:
        - name: "Update repository"
          apt:
              update_cache: "yes"
        - name: "Installing requirements"
          apt:
              name:
                   - "ca-certificates"
                   - "curl"
                   - "gnupg"
                   - "lsb-release"
              state: latest
        - name: "creating keyring dir if not existing"
          file:
               path: "/etc/apt/keyrings"
               state: directory
               recurse: yes
        - name: "Adding docker's GPHG key"
          shell: 'curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg || /bin/true'
          async: 20
          poll: 2
        - name: "Setting up repo"
          shell:
                'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null'
        - name: "Re-Update repository"
          apt:
              update_cache: "yes"
        - name: "Installing docker"
          apt:
              name:
                   - "docker-ce"
                   - "docker-ce-cli"
                   - "containerd.io"
                   - "docker-compose"
                   - "docker-compose-plugin"
              state: latest
          notify:
            - "starting docker service"
            - adding user to docker group
            - re-evaluating group membership
  handlers:
    - name: "starting docker service"
      systemd:
        - name: docker
          state: started
          enabled: true
        - name: containerd
          state: started
          enabled: true

    - name: adding user to docker group
      user:
        name: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
        groups: docker
        append: "yes"

    - debug:
        msg: "checking out if something is wrong"

    - name: re-evaluating group membership
      shell:
        'newgrp docker || /bin/true'
```

For some reason which I cannot understand, I get an error near the handler that starts the docker and the containerd services. This happens regardless of where I place that handler task. So it doesn't matter if the systemd related handler is first second or last. The error is always at this line:

> - name: "starting docker service"

and it says

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/home/ansible/DevOpsPractice/DevOpsScripts/InstallDockerUbuntu.yaml': line 55, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:
    - name: "starting docker service"
      ^ here
```

I am lost about what am I doing that is throwing this error

Answer (score 1):

I was making a typical noob error with the systemd module. So instead of

```
- name: "starting docker service"
  systemd:
    - name: docker
      state: started
      enabled: true
    - name: containerd
      state: started
      enabled: true
```

it should be

```
- name: start docker and containerd
  systemd:
    name:
      - docker
      - containerd
    state: started
    enabled: true
```

Silly mistake but I hope it helps someone